# Azure DevOps Deployment Groups - Is it possible to ignore targets that are offline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I have a hunch I'm going down the wrong rabbit hole here, but thought I'd ask.

We have 4 servers in a Deployment Group, but we don't always run all 4 of them (cost savings, etc.). What I would like to know is whether I can have the Release deploy only to the online targets and skip the ones that are offline, without failing the build.

Obviously, should we use more servers again that they would need deploying to, etc. as they would not be updated.

The danger here is of course misreading an offline server as legitimate instead of a failed deployment, hence my rabbit hole suspicion.

How do you manage releases to a stage that has multiple servers that operate elastically-ish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, I've just [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) debugged myself.

I can simply disable the target in `Deployment Groups` (under *Organisation* level settings), or alternativly, I can apply `tags` to the targets (e.g. Active) and use that as a filter in the stage tasks.